# It's 2017 but "...requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load."

Tags: support, bug

I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260115/whats-this-stack-overflow-requires-external-javascript-from-another-domain-w) but this one is way back 2014 and supposed to be adding `https://` will work. But as what I also read from [here](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/) that `https://` was already implemented thus, I already have `https://` in my web browser's url field and it is labeled as "Secured". When I checked the dev tools I've got a bunch of errors like: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` and `Uncaught TypeError` which is basically because some `js` failed to load.

I'm under a corporate proxy and what confused me, this error happen randomly. Sometimes it pop-up, and after like 30 minutes or an hour it disappear and the site works normally. I tried clearing the cache, updating the browser, restarting the browser and the whole pc(sometimes it returns to normal, maybe because the error disappear randomly?) but it still goes the same sometimes.

The error shows in Chrome browser, I can't test Firefox because somehow it refuse to connect to our corporate proxy. I'm using IE10 to post this one.

<strike>It happens to all the sites, except **[Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/)**, maybe because of Aliens?</strike>

EDIT: AREA51 has errors too, it's just that the error banner don't appear

According to Ilmari Karonen, I should try to paste the url [ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js), yes I can access the js file, but if I place `https` before the url I get the error:

**`Your connection is not private`**

And under the advanced I get this:

> ajax.googleapis.com normally uses encryption to protect your
>   information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to
>   ajax.googleapis.com this time, the website sent back unusual and
>   incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to
>   pretend to be ajax.googleapis.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has
>   interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because
>   Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.
>
> You cannot visit ajax.googleapis.com right now because the website
>   uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this
>   page will probably work later.

[image: Screenshot Chrome Dev]

Comment: Next time this happens, try pasting the URL https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js (or whichever URL is giving you the `ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` error) directly into the address bar and pressing enter, and see what the error page (assuming you get one) says; don't forget to click the "Advanced" button for more info. It's possible that your corporate proxy is messing with your HTTPS connections somehow, causing this error.

Comment: yeah, forgot to mention that. I read it from the previous posts comments. I get no error in that. I can access(view) the js file in the browser after I pasted it just now.

Comment: BTW it still happening right now. I'm using IE10. This is the time I'm only thankful to IE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about a misconfigured corporate proxy or firewall.

Comment: As Nathan suggests above, this is clearly a problem with your corporate environment. Google is telling you as much in that error, where it's basically telling you "this is not what we expected to get from this domain." I've gotten the same type of error when trying to access sites from hotel Wi-Fi where they redirect all requests to their standard login screen before you can do anything. There's nothing *we* can do about it because the problem is not on our side.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Is it possible to experience `https://` issue to stackexchange sites but not gmail? or other sites using `https://` connection?

Comment: @threeFatCat: Almost certainly, depending on the weird details of exactly *how* your proxy does its stuff.

Comment: that would be fine, by just now the error disappeared in the chrome and the site returns to the normal functionality. My concern was it just happened randomly. Thanks for the feedback then.